# How closely related are aspect-oriented programming to macros?

Tags: clojure, lisp, scheme

I've heard the term 'aspect oriented programming' tossed around for a long time... I'm still confused... However, it seems to me that the general definition of an aspect is that you can take an existing program, annotate it using an 'aspect' of some sort and have it produce an additional behavior or something completely different. It kinda smells like a macro to me. I'm wondering if there are any similarities/differences as well as any informative links on this matter.

Comment: Here is the wrong place to ask. Stackoverflow FAQ says: 'You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.'

Comment: And so the SO admins strike again, closing yet another question. What purpose does closing the question serve when the question has not been answered? Perhaps there could be some mentoring going on instead which coach an OP to produce a better question.

Comment: @Frank THANK YOU! I didn't think the question was as dumb, chatty or open-ended as some other questions with 200+ votes I've seen on SO.

Comment: AOP can be trivially implemented on top of macros (but there are many other ways). General purpose macros cannot be implemented on top of such a limited and trivial thing as AOP. Therefore, there's no relationship whatsoever.

Comment: For an example of what @SK-logic says see: https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke

Comment: I would say that there are some similarities between macros and AOP, but only in a metaphorical sense.